# How do I set optional arguments in the conda environment.yml file?

Tags: python, anaconda, yaml, conda

I am currently working with GeoPython - Auto GIS. After research on the [work flow with conda+python](https://tdhopper.com/blog/my-python-environment-workflow-with-conda/), I have found out how to create and specify the packages in an environment.yml file. But I found no way to specify an optional arguement. An example is as follows,

The equivalent of this conda command

```
conda install -y -c conda-forge geopandas
```

is the following in environment.yml

```
name: parkar
channels:
- conda-forge
- defaults
dependencies:
- geopandas
```

([See how conda environment files are made at section Conda Environment Files of this link](https://tdhopper.com/blog/my-python-environment-workflow-with-conda/))

But I could not find a way to specify the following command [a],

```
conda install -y -c conda-forge basemap=1.0.8.dev0 --no-deps
```

I did try it like this,

```
- basemap=1.0.8.dev0 --no-deps
```

But ended up with the following promt when I ran `conda env update --file environment.yml`

```
CondaValueError: invalid package specification: basemap=1.0.8.dev0 --no-deps
```

I also tried exporting the environment.yml file of the 'base' conda environment after running the above command [a] and got the following line where basemap=1.0.8.dev0 dependency was at,

```
  - basemap=1.0.8.dev0=np111py35_1
```

Any one ever encountered this problem or has a solution?

Comment: conda install docs can be found at https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-install.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specifying the optional argument as follows resulted in avoiding the above error

```
- basemap=1.0.8.dev0 [--no-deps]
```